# Bootable USB of Ubuntu 13.04 without the gui?

Tags: usb

I was wondering if there is a way to create a USB Bootable Image of Ubuntu without the gui such as making it text based?

Comment: Refer to this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/479356/225679 . It actually explains 14.04 installation in text based installer(i.e minimal CD) but the same can be applied to 13.04 so far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

Sure take a [ubuntu minmal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) installation CD!