# Ubuntu install graphical error

Tags: 12.04, graphics, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a (used and not that new) laptop. I booted with a normal installation CD (DVD) But it says it tried to start the graphic device but fails. After that the screen goes black and flickers.

Does that mean that my laptop not supports this version of Ubuntu, or does it? What can I do?

NB: The laptop is a ACER aspire 3000

Comment: Any reason why you don't tried with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?

Comment: http://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-3000/ -- Review Date: Mar. 2, 2006 -- Updated on: Mar. 2, 2006 -- There seems to be reason to choose some other distribution, X/K/L-Ubuntu comes to mind.

Comment: Can you provide us with additional specs? I believe that system came with 256MB of RAM. Is this that case or was it upgraded?

Comment: try with the text based based installer(i.e minimal CD). See [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/479356/225679)

Answer (score 0):

That guy had the same problem as you. 
-> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213378

See if it helps. Basically your specs cause trouble with ubuntu. Seems he installed on low graphics mode.